# IF Formula returning error or not doing a section of the formula

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a formula in my report to select a field based on requirements:

```
 if not isnull({EXT_TBL.EXT_KEY_TYPE}) then

(if {EXT_TBL.EXT_KEY_TYPE} = "SO" and  {EXT_TBL.EXT_ACTION_FLAG_9} = "Y"
then {EXT_TBL.EXT_TEXT})

else '0'
```

When I run the report it works ok until I try to load a specific page. When I try to load the page I get an error of 'The string is non numeric'. The formula is called in another formula:

```
{COR_TBL.COR_EXPECTED_DATE} + 2 + ToNumber({@FRM_NOTES})
```

I have ran the query on the server of:

```
SELECT * FROM EXT_TBL WHERE EXT_KEY_TYPE = "SO" AND EXT_ACTION_FLAG_9 = "Y";
```

This returned me two rows of data. I have narrowed it down to a specific entry that is causing the issue, but in the database the row has N in the field action flag 9 instead of Y so it shouldn't be throwing me the error in my report.

The action field 9 is flagged on only two records both of which contain a 7 in the EXT_TEXT feild so I have no idea why I am getting the error.

I also tried a nested if statement of:

```
if not isnull({EXT_TBL.EXT_KEY_TYPE}) then

(if {EXT_TBL.EXT_KEY_TYPE} = "SO" then (if {EXT_TBL.EXT_ACTION_FLAG_9} = "Y"
then {EXT_TBL.EXT_TEXT}))

else '0'
```

But it still gave me the same error.

Thanks

Comment: what's the output of this formula {COR_TBL.COR_EXPECTED_DATE} + 2 + ToNumber({@FRM_NOTES})?

Comment: It is a date. So the formula takes the date in the DB and adds 2 to it plus whatever was entered in the EXT_TBL in field 9, or 0 if field 9 wasn't 'Y', at least that is what I am wanting to happen.

Comment: i'm not sure about adding 2 on the date... does it give you a correct date?

Comment: Yeah it adds 2 days onto the date. From what I understand is that there is one record that has just a string of text, albeit with the ACTION_FLAG_9 is N so it should be registering 0 with the formula but it is trying to put the string of text to a number which it can't do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by removing the nested if statement and just putting all the conditions in the original statement:

```
if not isnull({EXT_TBL.EXT_KEY_TYPE}) AND {EXT_TBL.EXT_KEY_TYPE} = "SO" 
AND {EXT_TBL.EXT_ACTION_FLAG_9} = "Y"

THEN {EXT_TBL.EXT_TXT} ELSE '0'
```

This seems to have fixed the issue.